# how to configure a local database so that it works in all computers

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio, app-config, publish

this is my app.config file. I am using vs 2012 with c#.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
</configSections>
<startup> 
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
</startup>
<connectionStrings>

<add name="Small_Business_Management.Properties.Settings.businessdataConnectionString1"
    connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\businessdata.mdf;Integrated Security=True"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />

 </connectionStrings>
 </configuration>
```

now i included the database file businessdat.mdf in the solution.Now when i publish the application it is not working in other computers.It works fine in mine. In other computers it asks me to install sql server.How can i publish with a local database so that it works without installing sql server in other computers

Comment: Are you deploying this to a web server?

Comment: @Anonymous If it's an **app**.config, I highly doubt it. =)

Comment: @J.Steen good point...My mind has been stuck on 'web' mode.

Comment: no i just created a database in sql server 2008 and and i copied the database file into the solution.

Comment: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/307353

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use the LocalDB functionality of SQL Server 2012 you **need to install the LocalDB functionality** on each device you deploy to. You can find the installer [here](http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXPCTAV2/enus/default.aspx).
It is possible to do a silent install, so you can include it in your application installer if you have one:

```
msiexec /i SqlLocalDB2012.msi /qn IACCEPTSQLLOCALDBLICENSETERMS=YES
```

more information [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh510202.aspx) and [here](http://www.sqlcoffee.com/SQLServer2012_0004.htm)

If you really do not want to (or can not) install anything on the devices you deploy to, you can always check out [sqlite](http://www.sqlite.org/)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have two choices:

1. Install LocalDB on the other computers - you may be able to integrate this into your installation/deployment process for the app.
2. Use an embedded database

To expand the above a bit, to avoid an installation you'll have to use an embedded database so that the necessary libraries are deployed with your application. In context the obvious choice would be SQL Server Compact which should work with the code and SQL you already have i.e. there's a reasonable chance you'll only need to add the files/references and change the connection string.